# Regular Expressions and EditPlus

Tags: regex, editplus

I'm using Edit Plus and have the following type of lines in a text file which represent a directory structure and a file.

```
\APPS\MCCSDOCS\GENERAL\10-11 ARRAT\BRIDGE RIVER_\BRIDGE RIVER-PA0900021_DEC 21.PDF
\APPS\MCCSDOCS\GENERAL\10-11 ARRAT\BURNS LAKE\BURNSLAKE_PA1100062-SE_MAR2010.XLS
\APPS\MCCSDOCS\GENERAL\10-11 ARRAT\CAMPBELL RIVER\CAMPBELLRIVER_PA0900004_ARRAT_OCT2010.PDF
```

What I need to do is grab the directory structure `\APPS\MCCSDOCS\GENERAL\10-11 ARRAT\BRIDGE RIVER_\`  and place it in buffer `/1`
and also grab the file name `BRIDGE RIVER-PA0900021_DEC 21.PDF` and place it in buffer `/2`.

If it is easier to start at the end of the line and grab the file name and then grab what is left, that would work too.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? And what do you mean by 'buffer'? Did you perhaps meant `\1` and `\2` instead of `/1` and `/2`?

Comment: Have a look at the wiki papge (https://editplus.info/wiki/Regular_expression_syntax) and this tutorial (http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/working-with-editplus-text-editor-regular-expression-how-to)

Answer (score 0):

```
(\\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\.*\\)(.*)   

\\ = literal \
.* = anything
```

The result will be:

```
\APPS\MCCSDOCS\GENERAL\10-11 ARRAT\BRIDGE RIVER_\=======BRIDGE RIVER-PA0900021_DEC 21.PDF
\APPS\MCCSDOCS\GENERAL\10-11 ARRAT\BURNS LAKE\=======BURNSLAKE_PA1100062-SE_MAR2010.XLS
\APPS\MCCSDOCS\GENERAL\10-11 ARRAT\CAMPBELL RIVER\=======CAMPBELLRIVER_PA0900004_ARRAT_OCT2010.PDF
```

Is this what you want?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
^[\s]*(.*\\)(.*\.[a-zA-Z]{3,5})[\s]*$
```

It seems this works in this case.

Added filename extension part **\.[A-z]{3,5}** and leading or trailing space checking part **[\s]*** of filepath string. Thanks:-)